# "Qualcuno" può essere definito un aggettivo indefinito?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-pronouns

Guardando sui dizionari ho notato che non viene dato come aggettivo, pur avendo spesso una funzione simile, come in questi due casi:

> 1) *Voglio mostrarti qualcuna delle mie invenzioni*

dove *qualcuna* si comporta come *qualche* in

> *Voglio mostrarti qualche mia invenzione*.

e

> 2) *- hai delle monetine?*
>     *- me n'è rimasta qualcuna in tasca*

dove *qualcuna* si comporta come *alcune* in

> *me ne sono rimaste alcune in tasca*.

Sbaglio qualcosa o c'è una spiegazione logica?

Comment: In entrambi i casi *qualcuno* è usato come pronome, non come aggettivo. Difatti nei dizionari *qualcuno* viene correttamente riportato come un pronome indefinito.

Comment: @Denis Nardin: " me ne sono rimaste alcune in tasca"  in questo caso quindi "alcuni" non è un aggettivo indefiniti ma un pronome?

Comment: Certo. Se fosse un aggettivo dovrebbe essere associato ad un sostantivo, e non c'è alcun sostantivo che svolga quel ruolo. Nota che [*alcuno*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alcuno/), che è una parola diversa da [*qualcuno*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/qualcuno/), può essere sia aggettivo che pronome

Comment: Per aggiungere alle perfette spiegazioni di Denis, “qualcuno” sarebbe un aggettivo se si potesse dire *“ho qualcuna monetina in tasca”, che però non si dice. Il ruolo corrispondente come aggettivo, più o meno, è svolto da “qualche”, come nel tuo primo esempio.

Comment: @DenisNardin: E adesso qualcuno potrebbe scrivere la risposta? Cominciano a proliferare molte domande senza risposta!

Comment: @Charo Hai ragione.. Avevo scritto un commento inizialmente perché non ero sicuro del motivo per cui Nakamura considerasse *qualcuno* come aggettivo nelle frasi, ma potrei cercare di scrivere una risposta spiegando come distinguere gli aggettivi dai pronomi indefiniti.

Answer (score 5):

Credo che ci sia un fraintendimento qui. In entrambi i casi *qualcuno* è usato come pronome. Infatti *qualcuno*, come dicono correttamente i dizionari, non può essere usato come aggettivo.

Con un'importante eccezione (il cosiddetto uso *predicativo* degli aggettivi qualificativi), che però non si applica mai agli aggettivi indefiniti, l'aggettivo in italiano accompagna sempre un sostantivo o un pronome. Di conseguenza nella frase seguente

> Me ne sono rimaste alcune in tasca

la parola *alcune* può avere solo la funzione di pronome. Forse la confusione può essere nata dalla frase molto simile

> Mi sono rimaste alcune monetine in tasca

dove in effetti *alcune* ha il ruolo di aggettivo, riferito al sostantivo *monetine*. Ma attenzione! La prima frase in realtà è molto più simile come struttura grammaticale alla seguente:

> Mi sono rimaste alcune delle monetine in tasca

dove *alcune* non fa più riferimento a *monetine* (che, anzi, forma in *delle monetine* un complemento partitivo retto da *alcune*), ed è quindi un pronome.

---

Confrontiamo ad esempio le frasi

> Mi è rimasta qualcuna delle monetine

che è perfettamente corretta, e dove *qualcuna* svolge la sua normale funzione di pronome, con la frase scorretta

> *Mi è rimasta qualcuna monetina

dove *qualcuna* sta cercando di svolgere la funzione di aggettivo, funzione a cui è mal adatto.

---

In sostanza: *qualcuno* è sempre un pronome, *alcuno* può essere entrambi e per distinguere i due casi il modo più semplice è cercare di vedere se *alcuno* è accompagnato da un sostantivo o (più raramente) un pronome che lo supportano.